# Why $S^n$ is the pushout of the inclusion $S^{n-1} \rightarrow D^n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, limits-colimits

**What will be the pushout for the following** :

[image]

where $i:S^{n-1} \rightarrow D^n$ is the inclusion of the boundary $S^{n-1}$ to the n-disk $D^n$.

According to **Pg 40 in Julia E. Bergner's The Homotopy Theory of (∞,1)-Categories**,

[image]

**pushout space should be** $S^n$ and I am guessing  quotient maps $\pi:D^n \rightarrow D^n/S^{n-1}=S^n$ will be its projection maps. I was trying to use the Universal property  of the quotient map to prove the Universal property of Pushout.

**My attempt:**
[image]

Let $\phi,\psi:D^n \rightarrow X$ be two continuous maps to some topological space $X$ such that  $\psi \circ i= \phi \circ i$

But to use the Universal property of quotient map or in other words to produce a unique $\theta: S^n \rightarrow X$ we need $\phi$ and $\psi$ **both have to be constant and equal on** $S^{n-1}$. But I am not seeing any reason why any arbitrary map $D^n \rightarrow X$ will be constant on the boundary.

So are my choices of projection maps $(\pi, \pi)$ are wrong ones? Or am I misunderstanding something?

I am confused.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: You have the wrong pushout projections. You should take the inclusions of the two "hemispheres" of $S^n$ instead.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not take the quotient map $\pi : D^n \to D^n/S^{n-1}$.

Instead let $j_+  : D^n \to S^n, j_+(x) = (x,\sqrt{1 - \lVert x \rVert^2})$, and $j_-  : D^n \to S^n, j_+(x) = (x,-\sqrt{1 - \lVert x \rVert^2})$. These maps embed $D^n$ as the upper and lower closed hemisphere. Then
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
S^{n-1}  @>{i}>> D^n \\
@V{i}VV @V{j_+}VV \\
D^n @>{j_-}>> S^n\end{CD}
is a pushout diagram. Im am sure you can fill the necessary details.

By the way, the canonical construction of the pushout is to take the disjoint union $D^n + D^n$ of two copies of $D^n$ and to identify the copies of $S^{n-1} \subset D^n$ via the identity map. This clearly gives a space homeomorphic to $S^n$.

Comment: Thank you Sir for the answer. I figured out my mistake.